# Azure SQL User Login for one database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am using azure sql ____.database.windows.net. in this database server I have two databases:

- DatabaseA / staging
- DatabaseB / production.

i need sql user login for only access to DatabaseB. Is it possible with create new sql user?

Comment: This will probably help you: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give user access to a DB in Azure SQL, you will have to perform one of the following things:

- create a user login in the master DB and then grant it access to appropriate DB
- create a user account within a desired DB

Nonetheless, you can follow the below path. First, create a new login:

```
CREATE LOGIN <login> WITH PASSWORD = '<password>';
```

Then create a user inside a DB:

```
USE <DB-name>
CREATE USER <user> FOR LOGIN <login>;  
GO
```

See more:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage